# Does Donald trump personally own trump tower in New York

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

Is he the owner of the building and is he free to sell it at any time if he wishes? And if he does, does that mean he did not have to pay for his penthouse in the building ?

Comment: I do not think this is political and no, Trump Organization owns Trump Tower, Donald Trump does not personally own it

Comment: He owns the mortgage on it. But he'd be free to sell it if he wished if he can pay off the mortgage...just like the owner of any property. He technically wouldn't have to pay rent, but that'd likely be a financially bad idea across his companies. There's benefits to paying out proper and valid business expenses. Note that a lot of other buildings with his name on it are *not* owned by him--but rather are buildings that paid Trump for use of his name.

Comment: @blip unless you have a reference that backs up that there is a "Mortgage" on the trump tower I think you are wrong.  There may be corporate debt involved but there is no mortgage or similar vehicle for large buildings like that.

Comment: @Chad You're probably right, but here's what wikipedia has: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_Tower_(New_York_City)#Opening_and_occupation

Comment: @blip yeah from the actual reference used - $80 million in bond debt secured by the property - thats not the same as a mortgage.  But its a common corporate debt vehicle

Comment: This is political because his campaign is paying rent to Trump Tower.  It's illegal for a campaign to pay the candidate money.  Campaign funds are supposed to pay other expenses, not compensate the candidate for use of resources.